# How can i iterate over image pixels in a faster manner in python?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I want to modify a grayscale image in a manner so that I can change the pixel values to black for the top half of the image. I can certainly do this by iterating over in the usual manner like this:

```
for i in range(0,rows):
  for j in range(0,cols):
    if(condition)
      image[i,j] = 0;
```

But this is quite slow as I have to do video processing. I can see that I have to use `Image.point()`, but I am not sure how to implement it. Can someone help me out in this?

Comment: Did you try numpy and arrays?

Comment: What is the condition? Does it depend on the row and column index, or the pixel value?

Comment: Well, i just wanted to set only half the image pixels to black. I just wrote in a manner for showing my issue, not actual code

Comment: Should the 50% of black pixels be contiguous, random, something else?

Comment: Contiguous.. top half of the image. I was going through numpy now, is it something like this? im[:rows/2,:] = 0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will be much faster if you convert the PIL image to a numpy array first.  Here's how you can zero all the pixels with a value below 10:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array(img)
>>> arr[arr < 10] = 0
>>> img.putdata(arr)
```

Or, as you stated in your comment, here's you'd black out the top half of the image:

```
>>> arr[:arr.shape[0] / 2,:] = 0
```

Finally, since you're doing video processing, notice that you don't have to loop over the individual frames either.  Let's say you have ten frames of 4x4 images:

```
>>> arr = np.ones((10,4,4)) # 10 all-white frames
>>> arr[:,:2,:] = 0         # black out the top half of every frame
>>> a
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
    [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]],

   [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
    [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]],
...
```

Comment: Looks like yours is right, but i did like this im[:rows/2,:] = 0

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good candidate for multiprocessing the image/s. If you split the image into blocks of pixels you can very easily process the image in parallel, that is if it is sufficiently large or you are doing this on a lot of images.

1. Break the image up into chunks defined as tuples ( top left X, top left Y, width, height )
2. Pass tuples and image handle to various threads, hopefully in a thread pool.
3. Wait for threads to finish and then continue using your image.

This, depending on the image size and your pick of the number of threads and block size, can speed up your process linearly up to a point of course.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but various threads for such a simple task ? Is nt it expensive ?

Comment: It is expensive, why I have the ending portion. After I typed it up it would make sense if you were doing this over a lot of images and or if the images have very large dimensions.