# Python mask image pixels from a set of values

Tags: python, image, performance, numpy, vectorization

Provided an image with labels (the value of a pixel corresponds to its label), and the list of labels that are accepted, I am trying to create a "mask" image with `255` value if the pixels label is accepted, `0` otherwise.

I know that this is a slow approach as it iterates over the image at python-speed (but it demonstrates the idea well):

```
mask = numpy.zeros(labels.shape[:2], dtype = "uint8")

for i in xrange(mask.shape[0]):
    for j in xrange(mask.shape[1]):
        if labels[i][j] in accepted:
            mask[i][j] = 255
```

I know that it is much faster to use python slicing and masking, but I do not know how to compose a complicated condition. I still get a tremendous speed-up when I mask the pixels one-by-one accepted label, like so:

```
for value in accepted:
    mask[labels == value] = 255
```

Can I somehow make a one-liner doing what I want? My python knowledge is rusty (read: almost no python in the last few years), so while I tried composing this using some examples I found, this is the closest I got:

```
mask[(labels in accepted).all()] = 255
```

And in this case I get the following error: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

I've looked at similar SO questions (e.g.[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461153/how-can-i-iterate-over-image-pixels-in-a-faster-manner-in-python) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26445153/iterations-through-pixels-in-an-image-are-terribly-slow-with-python-opencv) and more) but they all seem to cover the cases where either the values are from a range or lower/higher than a threshold (<10) , or where the image slice to change is continuous.

Any suggestion on how check "is value among accepted values" would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the meantime, I found an acceptable-speed solution to my own question:

```
mask = numpy.zeros(labels.shape[:2], dtype = "uint8")
mask[numpy.in1d(labels, accepted).reshape(mask.shape)] = 255
```

It consists in first using [`numpy.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to get a boolean array from the `labels` array, and check which ones are present in `accepted` (element-wise function of the python keyword "in").

As this apparently necessarily returns a 1D array, even if it can be applied to a 2D array (it simply unravels the array), so I follow by using `reshape()` to make the boolean array dimensions correspond to that of the `mask`.

Finally, I use this boolean array to index the required elements of `mask` and set them to a desired value.

Comment: @rayryeng Honestly, I did not _need_ to make your solution work once I worked this one out myself -- but at this point it is more of a professional curiosity and liking problem-solving that won't give me peace - I just want to know why I can't reproduce your example, for the sake of reproducing it :D

Comment: This worked amazingly - from 72 hours with 1 for-loop to 40 seconds with numpy's in1d on my work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`list_pixels = np.array( [img[x,y,:] for x,y in zip(np.where(bool_obj)[0], np.where(bool_obj)[1])] )`