# Mask an image where masked pixels exist in list of pixel values

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to mask an image where the masked values correspond to any one of several of values in a list.

Consider the following "image" and "pixel values"

```
import numpy

img = numpy.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3) #something to represent an image
pixels = [numpy.array([0,1,2]), numpy.array([9,10,11])] #arbitrarily selected "pixel" values
```

I am trying to come up with some procedure that will output a 2d mask array where masked values correspond to pixel values in the list `pixels`

Goal:

```
In [93]: mask
Out[93]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Attempt 1 from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43098389/python-mask-image-pixels-from-a-set-of-values):

```
mask = numpy.zeros( img.shape[:2], dtype = "uint8" )
mask[numpy.in1d(img, pixels).reshape(mask.shape)] = 1
```

This results in `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 27 into shape (3,3)`
I believe this answer assumes a 2d input as `img`

Attempt 2:

```
mask = numpy.zeros(img.shape[:2])
for x,y in [(x,y) for x in range(img.shape[0]) for y in range(img.shape[1])]:
    if img[x,y,:] in pixels:
        mask[x,y] = 1
```

This results in `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`, but imagine there's a more concise approach than looping through each value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Setup***

Make sure your `pixels` is a `numpy.array` first:

```
pixels = np.array(pixels)
```

---

You can make use of broadcasting here, just be careful that the memory requirement is not too high:

```
(img[:, None] == pixels[:, None]).all(-1).sum(1)
```

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a ValueError, because you use np.array as "input" for if statement. But it has to be a bollean or a number. When you use `numpy.all`, you turn numpy array into boolean (it is True when all elements are diffrent then zero).

**Solution**

```
for x,y in [(x,y) for x in range(img.shape[0]) for y in range(img.shape[1])]:
        if numpy.all(numpy.isin(img[x, y, :], pixels)):
            mask[x,y] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `pixels` to a list of lists and then you can do this by using simple list comprehension:

```
pixels = [list(pixel) for pixel in pixels]
mask = [[int(list(row) in pixels) for row in i] for i in img]
```

OUTPUT:

```
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

`np.array` returns a value for each element when you do a comparison using `==`, which is why it gives you that error when you compare using `in`. `sublist in list` returns a single truth value.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I found which is faster than the other answers so far and requires minimal additional memory:

```
mask = numpy.zeros( img.shape[:2], dtype=bool )
for pixel in numpy.unique(pixels, axis=0):
    mask |= (img == pixel).all(-1)
```