# Issue with numpy behaviour, seems determined by array size, effecting boolean output

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm having an issue with some numpy code, wherein im comparing an np.array representation of an image (y,1,x,3) with an np.array list of pixel values, [a,b,c,d] etc. of shape [n,1,3].

However when n grows larger than 42 the end results of im==list is no longer a list of tuple comparisons, and instead becomes False.

Any clarification on why this might be happening would be much appreciated, as the former result of tuple comparisons is what I really need.

```
img = cv2.imread("example.png",cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
n = 8 # Number of pixel values for comparison
# Below is the declaration of example data from my usecase, specify n to see troublesome behaviour
pixels = [np.array([np.array([255, 255, 255]), np.array([254, 254, 254]), np.array([252, 252, 252]), np.array([253, 253, 253]),
       np.array([251, 251, 251]), np.array([250, 250, 250]), np.array([254, 254, 251]), np.array([253, 253, 250]),
       np.array([252, 255, 252]), np.array([253, 253, 246]), np.array([255, 252, 252]), np.array([247, 254, 250]),
       np.array([252, 255, 255]), np.array([252, 252, 249]), np.array([245, 255, 255]), np.array([255, 255, 252]),
       np.array([254, 251, 251]), np.array([250, 253, 250]), np.array([251, 254, 251]), np.array([254, 250, 247]),
       np.array([251, 254, 254]), np.array([253, 250, 253]), np.array([251, 248, 251]), np.array([255, 248, 248]),
       np.array([252, 249, 252]), np.array([255, 252, 255]), np.array([254, 251, 254]), np.array([248, 255, 255]),
       np.array([250, 253, 253]), np.array([253, 250, 250]), np.array([255, 254, 254]), np.array([249, 249, 252]),
       np.array([246, 253, 253]), np.array([247, 254, 254]), np.array([250, 254, 247]), np.array([249, 252, 252]),
       np.array([254, 254, 247]), np.array([244, 254, 254]), np.array([248, 251, 251]), np.array([248, 255, 251]),
       np.array([247, 250, 254]), np.array([255, 250, 250]), np.array([251, 251, 254]), np.array([252, 252, 255]),
       np.array([255, 248, 251]), np.array([250, 250, 253]), np.array([248, 255, 248]), np.array([245, 255, 251]),
       np.array([248, 251, 255]), np.array([255, 251, 248]), np.array([251, 255, 248]), np.array([254, 254, 244]),
       np.array([245, 251, 255]), np.array([255, 248, 255]), np.array([255, 255, 248]), np.array([251, 248, 255]),
       np.array([254, 247, 250]), np.array([255, 251, 251]), np.array([253, 246, 253]), np.array([250, 247, 254]),
       np.array([241, 255, 255]), np.array([248, 248, 255]), np.array([254, 250, 250])])]
pixel_for_insp = pixels[0][:n]
chck = (img[:, None] == pixel_for_insp[:, None])
```

Comment: Just a note the 1 dimensions in the QS are from the final step [:,None]

Comment: Your construction of `pixel_for_insp` is confusing.  It produces a (2,1,1,3) array.  `pixels` is a list containing a (2,3) array, then you index the list, and add a couple of `None` dimensions.

Comment: In new enough numpy versions, if there's  mismatch in dimensions (taking into account broadcasting), we get a DeprecationWarning and the simple `False`.  When dimensions match we get a multidimensional boolean array, an element-wise testing.  For `==` the same broadcasting rules apply as for `+` .

Comment: I understand the dimension mismatch issues, it's more a concern where given this same size format if we go from a 2,3 array to say a 43,3 array the mismatch occurs. for 2,3 or 4,3 or 15,3 etc. it produces the desired multidimensional boolean array

Comment: Just for reference this code follows the same format as in this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52560765/mask-an-image-where-masked-pixels-exist-in-list-of-pixel-values

Comment: Be clearer about which dimensions give the problem.

Comment: If the list of possible pixel values for detection increases in length, currently in the code there are only two possible 3-channel pixel values, over 42, so if there are 43 or more 3-channel pixel values, the result stops being an element-wise comparison and becomes the simple False. I don't understand why simply having more than 42 possible pixel values causes this behaviour.

Comment: Without a [mcve] we can't help.

Comment: When run in isolation, as provided above, the error does not occur, which makes me think it is a memory error that is not being flagged, but instead being given some fallback behaviour. Which is unhelpful to say the least